# Selenium WebDriver - Edge driver has Sidebar - need do disable

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-edgedriver

I am using Selenium / Java and the edge driver. Edge keeps displaying a Side bar that takes screen focus, causing my scripts to error. I cannot figure out which edge option it takes to disable this side bar. Below is my current code when setting up the Edge Driver. Can someone please help with the edge option I would need to get this bar to disable?

```
    case "edge":
        
        
        HashMap<String, Object> edgePrefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        edgePrefs.put("profile.default_content_settings.popups",0);
        edgePrefs.put("profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications",2);        
        edgePrefs.put("profile.default_content_setting_values.automatic_downloads" ,1);     
        edgePrefs.put("profile.content_settings.pattern_pairs.*,*.multiple-automatic-downloads",1);
        
        EdgeOptions egdeOptions = new EdgeOptions();
        egdeOptions.setExperimentalOption("prefs",edgePrefs);
        
        WebDriverManager.edgedriver().setup();
        driver = new EdgeDriver(egdeOptions);
        break;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZNgn.png)

See code above for what was tried.
Please see screenshot

Answer (score 1):

I've tried going into the Preferences file, which can be found here *edge://version/* listed as the "Profile path". Set different profile preferences like to not show hub apps, vertical tabs, or the sidebar, but didn't have much luck.

However, using a guest profile does resolve the issue as well as removes the "Personalize your web experience" prompt you sometimes get. Here's the command line switch you would use.

```
edgeOptions.AddArguments("--guest");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Here is the code logic to handle the notification
EdgeOptions options = new EdgeOptions();                        
options.addArguments("--start-maximized");      
Map<String, Object> prefs = new LinkedHashMap<>();          
prefs.put("user_experience_metrics.personalization_data_consent_enabled", Boolean.valueOf(true));           
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);          
driver = new EdgeDriver(options);
```